# Splunk Query to list the usage of Reports

Tags: report, splunk

I need a query to list down the frequency of usage of reports in Splunk. I tried few queries from mysplunk but it did not give the result. Thanks for any inputs.

Comment: It would help if you shared the queries you've tried as well as how the results of those queries don't meet your expectations.

Comment: you may be able to look at some of the `_*` indices ... but without knowing what you're actually wanting / have tried, answering this is going to be very difficult

Comment: Query to get the list of saved searches (Reports) - 
`|rest /servicesNS/-/-/saved/searches |table title eai:acl.owner eai:acl.app as app` 

Query to get the scheduled reports `| rest /services/saved/searches | where is_scheduled=1 | table title cron_schedule eai:acl.app` 

I need one final Query to list down the usage of Reports. for example XYZ report was used 400 times in the last 1 month

Answer (score 0):

Reports are a subset of saved searches.  Find them with this query:

```
| rest /servicesNS/-/-/saved/searches splunk_server=local
| search alert_type="always"
```

Once you have the list of reports, use it to filter the access logs.

```
index=_internal source="*access.log" status=200 [
  | rest /servicesNS/-/-/saved/searches splunk_server=local
  | search alert_type="always" 
  | replace " " with "%20" in title | return 1000 $title ]
| stats count by uri
```